# react-native scrollView is not properly woking for me

Tags: css, react-native

i have tries so many times but when usting different component in scroll body it just not adjust on to the content therefor some content are not included in scrollView. it has cut as shown as in the image..any sugession for fix..?

***sample code i used***

```
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

some code in the class

```
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.middleview}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textinputs}
                            placeholder="Location"
                            placeholderTextColor='grey'
```

### />

```
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>
                                Post Ad
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                   </view>
                  </scrollView>
```

styles used

```
    textinputs: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingTop: '2%',
        paddingBottom: '2%',
        paddingLeft: '4%',
        paddingRight: '4%',
        width: '90%',
        borderRadius: 50,
        margin: '3%',
        color: 'grey',
        height: '8%', 
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: .8,
        elevation: 10,

    middleview:{

        backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
        flex: 1,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
```

[here is the image below its cut the component scroll view is ended in the middle of components..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvBxv.jpg)

Comment: `<ScrollView style={styles.middleview}>` Try applying style to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to the scrollview using "contentContainerStyle" 
Working eg: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/rebellious-cookie